# Algorithm/Tool to convert pMathML to cMathML?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mathml

Does any one know of any known algorithm and/or open source project that converts presentation mathml to content mathml?

Javascript is preferable if there is any open source project. But any other language is appreciated too.

If not, do you have any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, you may know this, but it is not possible to reliably convert from presentation mathml to content mathml.  Its better to start and edit in content mathml because you can reliably convert to presentation mathml whenever you want.

The power math packages, like Mathematica, can effectively do a conversion from presentation mathml to content mathml... but they will have to guess in some cases at the meaning.

For an open source solution, I'd lookup "computer algebra system"... there are several good ones out there... perhaps they can do it, indirectly.

The last option would be to embed one of the editors... for example, Integre and MathType both support both presentation and content mathml... so, perhaps one can help you make the conversion.